# How to config nginx to run angular4 application

Tags: angular, nginx

I am new to angular and I would like to put the application on `Nginx` server on a docker container.

## 1. Running the angular application through @angular/cli

To do that, I did the following steps:

### 1.1. Installation of @angular/cli and creation of an angular4 application

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
ng new angular4-on-nginx-with-docker
```

### 1.2. Serving the application through `npm start`

The angular application is working correctly through

```
npm start
```

Now, I want to avoid the command `npm start` because I am thinking about developing a dockerized application. To do that, below is:

## 2. Running the angular application on nginx

### 2.1. `Dockerfile` file for nginx

```
FROM debian:jessie

MAINTAINER NGINX Docker Maintainers "docker-maint@nginx.com"

ENV NGINX_VERSION 1.11.9-1~jessie


RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pgp.mit.edu:80 --recv-keys 573BFD6B3D8FBC641079A6ABABF5BD827BD9BF62 \
    && echo "deb http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/debian/ jessie nginx" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends --no-install-suggests -y \
                        ca-certificates \
                        nginx=${NGINX_VERSION} \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# forward request and error logs to docker log collector
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /var/log/nginx/access.log \
    && ln -sf /dev/stderr /var/log/nginx/error.log


EXPOSE 80 443

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

### 2.2. The config of nginx is below:

```
server {
    server_name angular4.dev;
    root /var/www/frontend/src;

    try_files $uri $uri/ index.html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/angular4_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/angular4_access.log;
}
```

### 2.3. The `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx:
    build: nginx
    ports:
      - 88:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/frontend:/var/www/frontend
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/logs/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
```

### 2.4. building the docker image and running the container

```
docker-compose up -d --build
```

### 2.5. Identification of the IP address of the container

```
docker inspect angular4onnginxwithdocker_nginx_1 | grep IPA
            #"SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            #"IPAddress": "",
            #        "IPAMConfig": null,
            #        "IPAddress": "172.18.0.2",
```

Open your browser on [172.18.0.2](http://172.18.0.2/)

## The issue

I think that npm packages are not accessible... I am not sure what is wrong exactly. But, what I can say is that the page is empty and without having any error message in the console.

Below is the code obtained when using `nginx`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular4 on nginx with docker</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

This the code of the page obtained by the use of the command `npm start`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular4 on nginx with docker</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

So, what is wrong???

A repo for that example is available on [github](https://github.com/mappedinn/angular4-on-nginx-with-docker)

Answer (score 33):

If anyone still struggling with production setup of angular 2/4/5 app + Nginx(i.e. Without Docker), then here is the complete solution:

Suppose you want to deploy your angular app at HOST: `http://example.com` and PORT: `8080`
Note - HOST and PORT might be different in your case.

Make sure you have `<base href="/">` in you index.html head tag.

1. Firstly, go to your angular repo (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld) path at your machine.
2. Then build /dist for your production server using the following command:

   ng build --prod --base-href http://example.com:8080
3. Now copy /dist (i.e. /home/user/helloWorld/dist) folder from your machine's angular repo to the remote machine where you want to host your production server.
4. Now login to your remote server and add following nginx server configuration.

   ```
   server {

       listen 8080;

       server_name http://example.com;

       root /path/to/your/dist/location;

       # eg. root /home/admin/helloWorld/dist

       index index.html index.htm;

       location / {

           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

           # This will allow you to refresh page in your angular app. Which will not give error 404.

       }

   }
   ```
5. Now restart nginx.
6. That's it !! Now you can access your angular app at http://example.com:8080

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 11):

One thing that's wrong is that you are trying to publish your source files, instead of doing a production build using the cli and publish the output of these files. `ng start` is used for **local** development. When you are happy with your outcome, you can use `ng build --prod` to build your application, and whatever resides in your `/dist` folder should be placed in the docker.

If you want to have everything in your docker, you should `ng build --prod` after creating your new project, and then point the root of your `nginx` to `/var/www/frontend/dist;`. This will highly increase the boot time of your docker though. Obviously depending on the size of your project

Answer (score 2):

If anyone still have problems serving angular with docker and ssl.

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:stable

## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/my-app /usr/share/nginx/html/


## Skip this if you are using kubernetes config map 
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Serve
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

Provide nginx.conf via kubernetes config map definition as follows:

```yaml
volumeMounts:
- mountPath: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  name: config
  subPath: nginx.conf
volumes:
- configMap:
    defaultMode: 420
    name: config-map-name
```

nginx.conf

```
worker_processes auto;
pid /tmp/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
  use epoll;
  multi_accept on;
}

http {
  # this is necessary for us to be able to disable request buffering in all cases

  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  log_format timed_combined 'remote_addr - '
    '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
    '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
    '$request_time $upstream_response_time $pipe';

  access_log /dev/stdout timed_combined;

  server {

    listen 0.0.0.0:443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    server_tokens off;


    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # SSL
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/cert/tls.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/cert/tls.key;

    # Recommendations from https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Strong_SSL_Security_On_nginx.html
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers '!aNULL:kECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AESGCM:RSA+AESGCM:kECDH+AES:ECDH+AES:RSA+AES:';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;

    # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
    client_max_body_size 0;

    # required to avoid HTTP 411:
    chunked_transfer_encoding on;

    location / {
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
  }
}
```