# Nginx configuration for Angular4 app

Tags: angular, nginx

I use angular-cli to make an angular4 app. I build my app with ng-build and get the dist directory with all my files.
I put that files into /var/www/html/my-app directory.
Here is my config for nginx :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name $hostname;
    root /var/www/html;
    merge_slashes on;

    location /my-app {
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

When I try www.my-domain.com/my-app
I get well my index but all the scripts file are in 404 not found because they are searched from www.my-domain.com/ and not from www.my-domain.com/my-app/

Is there someone who can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you specify the URI of the scripts?

Comment: I fix it by building my app with ng build --bh /my-app/

Comment: But if I refresh the browser it send me 404

Comment: Error in nginx log? Also what url did the browser hit?

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to config nginx to run angular4 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45277183/how-to-config-nginx-to-run-angular4-application)